# FireFox CSS Animations not functioning.

Tags: html, css, firefox

Over at blog.etree.biz/shops.html `@keyframe` is not working on the firefox browser.

```
<style>
.content-fauxcolumns, .content {
 background-image: url("http://www.etree.biz/wp-content/themes/Etree%20Theme/images/jkbg.jpg");
-webkit-animation: backgrounds 30s infinite;
    animation: backgrounds 30s infinite;

}
@-webkit-keyframes backgrounds {
    0%   {background-image: url("http://www.etree.biz/wp-content/themes/Etree%20Theme/images/ascotbg.jpg");}
    20%   {background-image: url("http://www.etree.biz/wp-content/themes/Etree%20Theme/images/jayseebg.jpg");}
    40%  { background-image: url("http://www.etree.biz/wp-content/themes/Etree%20Theme/images/winebg.jpg");}
    60%  {background-image: url("http://www.etree.biz/wp-content/themes/Etree%20Theme/images/shedbg.jpg");}
    80% {background-image: url("http://www.etree.biz/wp-content/themes/Etree%20Theme/images/snowbg.jpg");}
    95% {background-image: url("http://www.etree.biz/wp-content/themes/Etree%20Theme/images/glovesbg.jpg");}
    100%   {background-image: url("http://www.etree.biz/wp-content/themes/Etree%20Theme/images/ascotbg.jpg");}
}

@keyframes backgrounds {
    0%   {background-image: url("http://www.etree.biz/wp-content/themes/Etree%20Theme/images/ascotbg.jpg");}
    20%   {background-image: url("http://www.etree.biz/wp-content/themes/Etree%20Theme/images/jayseebg.jpg";);}
    40%  { background-image: url("http://www.etree.biz/wp-content/themes/Etree%20Theme/images/winebg.jpg");}
    60%  {background-image: url("http://www.etree.biz/wp-content/themes/Etree%20Theme/images/shedbg.jpg");}
    80% {background-image: url("http://www.etree.biz/wp-content/themes/Etree%20Theme/images/snowbg.jpg");}
    95% {background-image: url("http://www.etree.biz/wp-content/themes/Etree%20Theme/images/glovesbg.jpg");}
    100%   {background-image: url("http://www.etree.biz/wp-content/themes/Etree%20Theme/images/ascotbg.jpg");}
}
.content-fauxcolumns, .etreefooter, #navlinks, .mainmenu, #navlinks:link, #navlinks:visited, .etreeMobileHeader {
background-color:#41873A;
color:#FFF;
-webkit-animation: backgroundColor 30s infinite;
    animation: backgroundColor 30s infinite;
}
@-webkit-keyframes backgroundColor {
    0%   {background-color:#41873A;}
    20%   {background-color:#B6B757;}
    40%  {background-color:#9C2757;}
    60%  {background-color:#749B1D;}
    80% {background-color:#284C9C;}
    95% {background-color:#AE4F06;}
    100%   {background-color:#41873A;}
}

@keyframes backgroundColor {
    0%   {background-color:#41873A;}
    20%   background-color:#B6B757;}
    40%  {background-color:#9C2757;}
    60%  {background-color:#749B1D;}
    95% {background-color:#AE4F06;}
    100%   {background-color:#41873A;}
}
#navlinks:hover, #navlinks:active {
background-color:#FFF;
}
</style>
```

From my knolage the simple animations version should work, however after following firefoxe's developer example i am still unable to get the code to function on that browser.

What is the issue, and is there a possible fix?

Comment: What does "not working" mean? At all? Not correctly? What?

Comment: Please give your complete code. And make a __Fiddle__.

Answer (score 0):

Last keyframe you have a "{" missing at 20%, don't know if it's beacause of it, but you should fixit anyway.

```
@keyframes backgroundColor {
    0%   {background-color:#41873A;}
    20%   background-color:#B6B757;}
    40%  {background-color:#9C2757;}
    60%  {background-color:#749B1D;}
    95% {background-color:#AE4F06;}
    100%   {background-color:#41873A;}
```

Background section :

```
@keyframes backgrounds {
    0%   {background-image: url("http://www.etree.biz/wp-content/themes/Etree%20Theme/images/ascotbg.jpg");}
    20%   {background-image: url("http://www.etree.biz/wp-content/themes/Etree%20Theme/images/jayseebg.jpg";);}
    40%  { background-image: url("http://www.etree.biz/wp-content/themes/Etree%20Theme/images/winebg.jpg");}
    60%  {background-image: url("http://www.etree.biz/wp-content/themes/Etree%20Theme/images/shedbg.jpg");}
    80% {background-image: url("http://www.etree.biz/wp-content/themes/Etree%20Theme/images/snowbg.jpg");}
    95% {background-image: url("http://www.etree.biz/wp-content/themes/Etree%20Theme/images/glovesbg.jpg");}
    100%   {background-image: url("http://www.etree.biz/wp-content/themes/Etree%20Theme/images/ascotbg.jpg");}
}
```

At the and of 20% you have a ';' in more

Comment: This fixes the color section, however the background are still not changing.

Comment: I just edit my answer, you got a ';' in more on the background section too (20% line of the 2nd declaration)

Comment: Fixed the issue, however the problem is still there.